# jQuery AJAX to C# Web Service ASMX From HTTPS to HTTP Domains

Tags: jquery, ajax, https, asmx

I create a webservice with Visual Studio (asmx page) that is calling an HTTP page:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=" + lat + "&lng="+lng);
```

This service is served through HTTPS:

```
    https://mydevdomain.com/geonames/Service1.asmx/getGeoname
```

Now when I call this service from `https://mydevdomain.com/page.html` with this jQuery code…

```
  var request= $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://mydevdomain.com/geonames/Service1.asmx/getGeoname",
      data: "{ 'lat':'"+coordinatesMap[f][1]+"', lng:'"+ coordinatesMap[f][2]+"'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json"
  });
```

… I have the classic alert on explorer that say me that there is NON-secure content!
Why? How is it possible that jQuery knows that the service is calling a non-secure page?

P.S. I did the service because I wanted to avoid the alert page.

Comment: just quickly while I look at this... I recall having the same issue and I had to incorporate a C# object for HttpCertificates and set the trust-level.  I'll look for the code...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but it fixed a similiar issue I had with that alert.

I used **[ServerCertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx)** to fix.  Not that it matters exactly but my class was a ASMX C# WebService (more below)

**Example below:**

```
//Force Trust with server
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
  Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors) {return (true); };

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://999.999.99/PI/services/UCP");
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
request.Accept = "text/xml";
request.Method = "POST";
```

**More Code**...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

[WebService]
public class UCPSvc : WebService {

    [WebMethod (Description="Proxy for ACS UCP WebService")]
    public XmlDocument Proxy()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```